# Can I book a train ticket on IRCTC as a non-Indian citizen?

Tags: trains, online-resources, bookings, indian-railways, irctc

It seems like you're required to have an Indian identity card or something. Is it possible, if you don't have one, or must you use another site?

Comment: @JohnathanReez - and others -  you realise 3 of the 4 answers on that question simply link to the site I said isn't usable?

Comment: Fortunately I also found cleartrip, which seat61 seems to vouch for

Comment: Anybody can register but you need an Indian mobile number to receive the verification code. Foreign credit cards are now accepted as pointed in [this answer](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78749/how-to-buy-irctc-tickets-outside-of-india-if-international-cards-does-not-appe). To register using your mobile number please see [this link](http://www.travelindiasmart.com/train_tickets.php).

Comment: @RedBaron there is a way to do it without a local number, as I went there in June. I'' try and add an answer when I get more time.

Comment: http://www.irctchelp.in/2016/01/indian-train-tickets-for-foreigners-rule.html - This link sort of provides some answers.

Comment: Primo opportunity to add more answers :)

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can. When registering, IRCTC will ask your nationality and you can provide the nationality accordingly. But Indian Railway have a rule that when travelling on reserved tickets, you must hold the original copy of any ID proof along with you.