# How to buy IRCTC tickets outside of India if "International Cards" does not appear in the list?

Tags: payment-cards, indian-railways, irctc

I'm trying to book a ticket a month in advance with a foreign credit/debit card. All the existing options do not work. The system says:

> All international Debit/Credit cards can also be used for ticket
>   booking through 'International Cards (Powered by ATOM)'.

but ATOM is not even in the list:

[image]

What do I do? Is it a typical/temporary issue?

Comment: Seems to be a transient issue as I can see "ATOM" option on my payment screen

Answer (score 11):

This must be a glitch. Wait for sometime and try again. The ATOM option is available to me.

[image: IRCTC payment option - Credit cards]

---

If this option is not available to you for a long time. Try the following workaround.

1. Transfer the cash required from your credit card to a wallet service like Paytm, Mobikwik, etc...
2. While paying in IRCTC select the option Cash card/Wallets.
3. Choose the Paytm/Mobikwik/any other wallet.
   [image: IRCTC payment - Cash card/Wallet option]

   ---

   *Note:* All the Cash cards/wallet except [Mobikwik](https://wallet.mobikwik.com/accounts/register/) requires a phone number starting with +91 i.e) in India. So Mobikwik is the best and only option at the time of writing.

Comment: Opening an account at Paytm/Mobikwik/etc requires owning a +91 number (text message is sent for account verification)

Comment: @Sparkler **Try Mobikwik.** It's signup page does not ask for a phone number. Just email and password. Sorry. I should have checked it before. I performed a check on all cash cards and only Mobikwik allows you to register without phone number. I will update this in my answer

Answer (score 4):

For future people.  I struggled with IRCTC for hours trying to pay with a foreign card and failed.  I tried 12go and it worked but they charged a R800 fee for a R500 ticket :P  Cleartrip has worked in the past but they billed me and no ticket (I am confident of a refund).

But then I found the trick with paying in IRCTC via Atom.  It is so damned counter-intuitive...but once cracked, it is easy.

Step through the booking process until  you come to the `review booking` page that looks like this

[image]

Click on Multiple Payment Service and you get this

[image]

And you are away.  It took me 8 hours of frustration to get my first booking because the obvious place to click was `debit card with PIN`.  Once I worked this out it took about 30 minutes to do 4 more bookings.

The next challenge is the Indian railway system itself :P